# react-bootstrap <Button> not working properly The background color not workıng just when hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

my project was workıng just fin till one day the buttons that i import from the react bootstrap background color stop working and i tried many ways to solve it
like using clasname or uninstall and install the bootstrap and bootstrap react agin but the same thing

```
      <Button
        color="secondary"
        className="btn-secondary"
        variant="secondary"
        onClick={() => setShowNote(false)}
      >
        Close
      </Button>
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: ok the button ıs showing up but the color and the background color is always white , just when i hover the button with the mous the colors works , without hovering the button non of the colors works except the border color